# Javafx MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE jar file

Tags: javafx, jar, media

When I create a jar package of my maven project, the program does not find my media files anymore. I found several similar question from the google, but none of them helped me.

I have tried all of these options:

1. Document Base: Works fine on IDE, jar package throws MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE

```
// I get documentBase from the class which extends Application
String documentBase = Application.getHostServices().getDocumentBase();
Media media = new Media(documentBase + "src/main/resources/music/music.mp3");
```

2. Paths.get: Works fine on IDE, jar package throws MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE

```
Media media = new Media(Paths.get("src/main/resources/music/music.mp3").toUri().toString());
```

3. Get resource: Throws null

```
Media media = new Media(Audio.class.getResource("/music.mp3").toString());
```

4. Inputstream: Throws null

```
InputStream in = Audio.class.getResourceAsStream("/music.mp3");
Media media = new Media(new InputStreamReader(in).toString());
```

5. Inputstream  with getClassLoader(): Throws null

```
InputStream in = Audio.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/music.mp3");
Media media = new Media(new InputStreamReader(in).toString());
```

The Audio class on my examples is an abstract class, which handles everything through static methods and variables. I am using Java 11.

EDIT:
Added the correct path to examples.

Comment: Where in the classpath/jar does the mp3 file end up? Depending on the ide you're using `/resources/music.mp3` or `/music.mp3` could be the correct path (approach 3) after deployment or the file could be not included. Furthermore assuming you're using a system where file names are not case sensitive using the wrong case could result in this issue; jar entries **are** case sensitive, even on windows...

Comment: BTW: please forget about approaches 4 and 5 (or better remember that those don't work): [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) uses `Object`'s `toString` implementation which means the result will be something like `java.io.InputStreamReader@<some hex sequence>`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using this path:

```
Media media = new Media(Audio.class.getResource("/music/music.mp3").toString());
```

Since my file was inside a folder "music" inside resources folder, I had to include it too. Also note that "music/music.mp3" does not work, it needs the slash in front of it. This is quite confusing since when adding Images to the project, it does not need the slash.

Thanks to @fabian for explaining why my approaches did not work.